# Route parameters and multiple controller types

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I have a asp.net web api, using attributes for routing on the controllers. There are no route attriutes on the action level. The route for accessing a resource is:

```
[Route("{id}"]
public MyApiController: ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(Guid id)
    { 
        // ...
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I want to create a search controller, I'd like the URL to be

```
[Route("search")]
```

But this results in an error: `Multiple controller types were found that match the URL`. Is it possible to make sure the exact matching route is selected before the generic one?

Technically, the phrase `search` could be a valid ID for the first controller, but as `{id}` is a guid, this will never be the case, thus I'd like to select the controller with the exact matching route.

Comment: What do you mean by "default route"? Can you show more code for context?

Comment: Sorry about that. We are talking about routes on controller level. Default route has no technical meanning, but it's the route for accessing the main resource for the API.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have `RoutePrefix` at the controller level then?

Comment: Would route prefix solve this? The route prefix would be `search` for the search controller and `{id}` for the other controller. Any string would still match `{id}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Route constraints** to do the job. For example you could constraint your ID route to accept only valid GUID's.

Here is an ID controller that accepts only GUID strings in the URL:

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("{id:guid}")]
public class MyApiController: ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(Guid id)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

The Search controller would  match to an url like `"/search"`. Here is the Search controller:

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("search")]
public class SearchController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Constraints will prevent matching conflicts in the router.