# MVC Route Attribute finds multiple controller types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have 2 routes matching however I need them both to match as they are.
I cannot use GUID or INT's I need it to be strings.

This Route should only be taken if it doens't match anything else.

```
[Route("{slug}", Order = 1)]
```

and this route should always be taken

```
[Route("eula", Order = 0)]
```

Any idea's on how to achieve this ?
I thought ordering might work apparently it doesn't

Showing my exact issue :
[Route parameters and multiple controller types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584113/route-parameters-and-multiple-controller-types)

Reproducing the error :

RouteConfig.cs :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Controllers :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("eula")]
    public ActionResult Eula()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
}

public class SlugController : Controller
{
    [Route("{slug}")]
    public ActionResult SluggedUrl(string slug)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your " + slug;

        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slug controller route is too general. `Order` attribute also applies to actions in the same controller.

Suggestion: add a convention-based route for the slug

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    //catch all route
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Slug",
        url: "{*slug}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Slug", action = "SluggedUrl"}
    );
}
```

And remove attribute route form `SlugController`

```
public class SlugController : Controller {
    public ActionResult SluggedUrl(string slug) {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your " + slug;

        return View();
    }
}
```

That way the more specific `eula` attribute route will get matched before the more general `slug` route